# 3D Simplex Noise Sudden Height Change

Tags: directx-11, noise, perlin-noise, procedural-generation, simplex-noise

I have a problem generating 3D Noise.

I've written a framework that uses DirectX11 to render everything.

I generate a Geo-sphere and modify the height values using a 3D Simplex Noise function.

The problem is that when I see the result I see sudden changes in height that are not noise like at all...

[image]

(the rectangle shape in the center of the picture)

I've modified the Persistence to 0.1 so the error is easily seen here...

[image]

I can't figure out the issue with the sudden height changes. This is an error, right?

I calculate the height with the following...

```
for( int i = 0; i < sphere.Vertices.size(); ++i )
{
    // seperate out our positions
    float x = sphere.Vertices[ i ].Position.x;
    float y = sphere.Vertices[ i ].Position.y;
    float z = sphere.Vertices[ i ].Position.z;

    // get our noise value ( -1 to 1 )
    float ix = noise.octavenoise3D( 10, 0.1, 0.5, x, y, z, perm, &grad3[0][0] );

    // pack our coordinates into a vector
    XMVECTOR curPos = { x, y, z };

    // get the normalized vector of our position
    XMVECTOR normPos = XMVector3Normalize( curPos );

    // seperate our normalzed x y and z 
     float normX = XMVectorGetX( normPos );
     float normY = XMVectorGetY( normPos );
     float normZ = XMVectorGetZ( normPos );

    // figure out the height of this specific vertice, maxHeight = sphereRadius / 3.0f;
    float height = ix * maxHeight;
    float change = height + sphereRadius;

    // calculate the offset x y and z by the noise
    float changeX = change * normX;
    float changeY = change * normY;
    float changeZ = change * normZ;

    // save our new x y and z
    vertices[ i ].Pos.x = x + changeX;
    vertices[ i ].Pos.y = y + changeY;
    vertices[ i ].Pos.z = z + changeZ;

    // calculate color based on noise value 
    float colorChange = ( 0.5f * ix );
    float color = 0.5f + colorChange;

    // save color value in r g b
    vertices[ i ].Color.x = color;
    vertices[ i ].Color.y = color;
    vertices[ i ].Color.z = color;
}
```

Also, changing the base coordinates of the function doesn't get rid of this weird output. (for anyone who thinks that starting at 0,0,0 was messing it up somehow)

**Noise Implementation**

float Noise::octavenoise3D( const float octaves, const float persistence, 
    const float scale, const float x, const float y, const float z, int *perm, int *grad3 )

```
float total = 0;
float frequency = scale;
float amplitude = 1;
float maxAmplitude = 0;
for( int i = 0; i < octaves; i++ ) 
{
    total = total + rawnoise3D( x * frequency, y * frequency, z * frequency, perm, grad3 ) * amplitude;

    frequency = frequency * 2;
    maxAmplitude = maxAmplitude + amplitude;
    amplitude = amplitude * persistence;
}
return total / maxAmplitude;
```

float Noise::rawnoise3D( const float x, const float y, const float z, int *perm, int *grad3 )

```
float n0, n1, n2, n3;

float F3 = 1.0 / 3.0;
float s = ( x + y + z ) * F3;
int i = fastfloor( x + s );
int j = fastfloor( y + s );
int k = fastfloor( z + s );

float G3 = 1.0 / 6.0;
float t = ( i + j + k ) * G3;
float X0 = i - t;
float Y0 = j - t;
float Z0 = k - t;
float x0 = x - X0;
float y0 = y - Y0;
float z0 = z - Z0;

int i1, j1, k1;
int i2, j2, k2;

if( x0 >= y0 )
{
    if( y0 >= z0 )
    {
        i1 = 0;
        j1 = 0;
        k1 = 1;
        i2 = 1;
        j2 = 1;
        k2 = 0;
    }
    else if( x0 >= z0 )
    {
        i1 = 1;
        j1 = 0;
        k1 = 0;
        i2 = 1;
        j2 = 0;
        k2 = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        i1 = 0;
        j1 = 0;
        k1 = 1;
        i2 = 1;
        j2 = 0;
        k2 = 1;
    }
}
else
{
    if( y0 < z0 )
    {
        i1 = 0;
        j1 = 0;
        k1 = 1;
        i2 = 0;
        j2 = 1;
        k2 = 0;
    }
    else if( x0 < z0 )
    {
        i1 = 0;
        j1 = 1;
        k1 = 0;
        i2 = 0;
        j2 = 1;
        k2 = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        i1 = 0;
        j1 = 1;
        k1 = 0;
        i2 = 1;
        j2 = 1;
        k2 = 0;
    }
}

float x1 = x0 - i1 + G3; 
float y1 = y0 - j1 + G3;
float z1 = z0 - k1 + G3;
float x2 = x0 - i2 + 2.0 * G3; 
float y2 = y0 - j2 + 2.0  *G3;
float z2 = z0 - k2 + 2.0  *G3;
float x3 = x0 - 1.0 + 3.0 * G3; 
float y3 = y0 - 1.0 + 3.0 * G3;
float z3 = z0 - 1.0 + 3.0 * G3;

int ii = i & 255;
int jj = j & 255;
int kk = k & 255;
int gi0 = perm[ ii + perm[ jj + perm[ kk ] ] ] % 12;
int gi1 = perm[ ii+ i1 + perm[ jj + j1 + perm[ kk + k1 ] ] ] % 12;
int gi2 = perm[ ii + i2 + perm[ jj + j2 + perm[ kk + k2 ] ] ] % 12;
int gi3 = perm[ ii + 1 + perm[ jj + 1 + perm[ kk + 1 ] ] ] % 12;

float t0 = 0.6 - ( x0 * x0 ) - ( y0 * y0 ) - ( z0 * z0 );
if( t0 < 0 ) 
{
    n0 = 0.0;
}
else 
{
    t0 = t0 * t0;
    n0 = ( t0 * t0 ) * dot( &grad3[ gi0 ], x0, y0, z0);
}

float t1 = 0.6 - ( x1 * x1 ) - ( y1 * y1 ) - ( z1 * z1  );
if( t1 < 0 )
{
    n1 = 0.0;
}
else 
{
    t1 *= t1;
    n1 = ( t1 * t1 ) * dot( &grad3[ gi1 ], x1, y1, z1);
}

float t2 = 0.6 - ( x2 * x2 ) - ( y2 * y2 ) - ( z2 * z2 );

if( t2 < 0 ) 
{
    n2 = 0.0;
}
else 
{
    t2 *= t2;
    n2 = ( t2 * t2 ) * dot( &grad3[ gi2 ], x2, y2, z2);
}

float t3 = 0.6 - ( x3 * x3 ) - ( y3 * y3 ) - ( z3 * z3 );
if( t3 < 0 ) 
{
    n3 = 0.0;
}
else 
{
    t3 = t3 * t3;
    n3 = t3 * t3 * dot( &grad3[ gi3 ], x3, y3, z3);
}

float final = 32.0 * ( n0 + n1 + n2 + n3 );
return final;
```

int Noise::fastfloor( const float x )

```
return x > 0 ? (int)x : (int)x - 1;
```

float Noise::dot( const int* g, const float x, const float y, const float z )

```
return g[0]*x + g[1]*y + g[2]*z;
```

Comment: The sphere is centered in the origin of axis? If not when you update the coordinates you should add the center position.

Comment: the sphere is centered in the world

Comment: How is `noise.octavenoise3D` implemented? It looks like the drop is around the main planes. I suspect there is a sign error. Have you used `fmod(a,1.0f)` instead of `a-floor(a)`?

Comment: I added the noise functions to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution...

Solution: I was silly.  I had a dumb error in my raw noise function but i fixed it now

This is the fixed part of the code

```
if( x0 >= y0 )
{
    if( y0 >= z0 )
    {
        i1 = 1;
        j1 = 0;
        k1 = 0;
        i2 = 1;
        j2 = 1;
        k2 = 0;
    }
    else if( x0 >= z0 )
    {
        i1 = 1;
        j1 = 0;
        k1 = 0;
        i2 = 1;
        j2 = 0;
        k2 = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        i1 = 0;
        j1 = 0;
        k1 = 1;
        i2 = 1;
        j2 = 0;
        k2 = 1;
    }
}
else
{
    if( y0 < z0 )
    {
        i1 = 0;
        j1 = 0;
        k1 = 1;
        i2 = 0;
        j2 = 1;
        k2 = 1;
    }
    else if( x0 < z0 )
    {
        i1 = 0;
        j1 = 1;
        k1 = 0;
        i2 = 0;
        j2 = 1;
        k2 = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        i1 = 0;
        j1 = 1;
        k1 = 0;
        i2 = 1;
        j2 = 1;
        k2 = 0;
    }
}
```

Turned out I had several incorrect values in the old one.

Comment: The old one was not obviously wrong, this one is not obviously correct. Is it possible to simplify this more so it's more readable?

Comment: I'm not sure. This code might be hard to read but it is pretty niche so now that its done, its done.